# In a Functional Component, how do you access props from the redux store using react-redux connect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a functional react component like below, how do you access the props that are sent over from the redux store, similar to how on a class component's `this.props` in `componentDidMount()` are accessible, shown in the comment below?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../../actions";

const ComponentName = () => {
    // componentDidMount() {
    //    this.props;
    // }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>???</div>
        </div>
    );
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { state };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ComponentName);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The props will be passed as the first argument of the functional component.

```
const ComponentName = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>{ props.something }</div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

You can find more details on the official document https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html